# Javascript Multidimensional arrays-keys and values

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

```
"charts":[
        {
          "key": "Passed",
          "values": [ [ 1442856661000, 13082504 ], [ 1442770260000, 34817 ]]
}
]
```

This is my JSON. How do i access one of the values, i.e, `charts.values[0][0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.charts` is an array, therefore you need an index for the access.

```js
var data = {
        "charts": [
            {
                "key": "Passed",
                "values": [
                    [1442856661000, 13082504],
                    [1442770260000, 34817]
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

document.write(data.charts[0].values[0][0]);
```